# Tengo dos arreglos usuarios y mascotas quiero mostrar las mascotas que registra cada usuario¿Como puedo iterar dos arrays en un mismo ngFor?

Tags: ionic4

Estoy trayendo los datos desde firebase donde creo un servicio que me trae TODAS las mascotas y ese servicio lo consumo en el componente.ts de mascotas igual para usuarios con su metodo que me trae todos los usuarios, quiero mostrar en una vista que se llama mis mascotas mostrar las mascotas registradas por el usuario logeado en firebase esta la estructura por colecciones de usuarios y mascotas.

Comment: crea un servicio anteior que te traiga ya esta relacion para que solo uses un solo servicio de consulta de usuario y sus mascotas

Answer (score 0):

Para recorrer dos arrays lo mejor es usar 2 ngFor, uno para cada array, puedes meter los ngFor dentro de ngContainers que no te afectan la estructura del DOM como lo haria un div. Si de verdad quieres hacer en un solo ngFor, podrias hacerlo conociendo cual de los dos es mas grande y usando los indices para acceder a ambos arreglos al mismo tiempo.

> ng-container to the rescue.
>
> The Angular ng-container is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM.

Seria algo asi:

```
</ng-container *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios">
  </ng-container *ngFor="let mascosta of mascotas">
     Muestras aqui lo que quieras.
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Esto te serviria para mostrar por ejemplo todos los usuarios con sus mascotas en una misma vista. Ahora, si lo que quieres es mostrar solo el usuario conectado con sus mascotas, lo mejor es hacer la consulta directo a firebase y que te regrese solo eso que necesitas, y asi te liberas de la carga en tu app de tener que procesar innecesariamente.

Tomando un ejemplo que se encuentra en la documentacion de firebase:

```
// Find all dinosaurs whose height is exactly 25 meters.
var ref = firebase.database().ref("dinosaurs");
ref.orderByChild("height").equalTo(25).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

Si tienes el id del usuario conectado en una variable, digamos userID, puedes consultar sus mascotas en firebase directamente.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    this.userID = user.uid
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  } 
});

if (this.userID){
  // Buscas las mascotas del usuario conectado
  var ref = firebase.database().ref("mascotas");
  ref.orderByChild("dueño").equalTo(this.userID).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key); 
  });
}
```

La consulta tambien puedes hacerla asi:

```
var misMascotas = firebase.database().ref("mascotas/dueño/" + this.userID)
```

(Todo esto cambiando usuarios, mascotas, dueño por los nombres en tu base de datos)

fuentes:
https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives consultado el 02/08/2019
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#ref consultado el 02/08/2019